# How to fire periodic actions using setTimeout and dispatcher in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux, redux

How/Where can I dispatch actions periodically? Using recursive `setTimeout` to make a countdown.

Taken from the example, something similar to this:

```
// Can also be async if you return a function
export function incrementAsync() {
  return dispatch => {
    (function _r() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        // Yay! Can invoke sync or async actions with `dispatch`
        dispatch(increment());
        _r();
      }, 1000);
    })();
  };
}
```

So is this a good idea, or there is a better approach to this problem, like using middlewares or creating actions from somewhere else?

I prefer a generic version of this, where I can control start/stop of the timer via the store.

I've setup a sample implementation please take a look at https://gist.github.com/eguneys/7023a114558b92fdd25e

Comment: As this does work, I probably wouldn't keep recreating a function that always looks the same but instead define it once.

Comment: have you tried setInterval? don't really understand what's async about your increment. Do remember that js event handling is not very precise

Answer (score 18):

The approach you suggest is fine, although a bit convoluted. In general, I'd set intervals inside component lifecycle methods (e.g. `componentDidMount` / `componentWillUnmount`) and avoid actions setting intervals on other actions.

If you absolutely need this flexibility, a better bet is to use [Rx](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS) for async management, and `dispatch` the actions at the very end of observable chain. This way you use Redux where it shines (synchronous updates) and leave asynchronous composition to Rx.